# Unpack Blender Asset Browser collections

Tags: collections, asset

I am currently expanding my asset browser and I am also including folders containing multiple objects, lights etc. This works great but I am unable to separate the individual components when I drop them into a new Blender project. In my context this doesn't allow me the ability to tweak lights or volume density for any of my 'drag and drop' studio setups.
Does anyone know if it's possible to separate asset collections upon use.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the Blender documentation I found the solution to this issue. Upon dragging and dropping an asset from the browser, which is an instanced collection, open the 'add collection' Tab (bottom left of viewport in my case) and uncheck the the Instance checkbox.